# Is this transformation of a sinusoidal function correct or not?

Tags: trigonometry

$f(x) = 2-4\cos(2x-\frac{1}{3}\pi)$

How do you get this function from as standard function?

My answer:

$ y = \cos x $

↓ Multiply with the x-axis, -4

$y=-4\cos x$

↓ Multiply with the y-axis, 0.5

$y=-4\cos 2x $

↓ Translation $(\frac{1}{6}\pi, 2)$

$f(x) = 2-4\cos(2x-\frac{1}{3}\pi)$

Is this answer correct? The only part I am really concerned about is the final translation, with the $(\frac{1}{6}\pi)$ instead of $(\frac{1}{3}\pi)$.

Comment: If you don't want bad answers, I might ask you first of all not to post a bad question. What on earth does "multiply with the x-axis" mean? Are you stretching along the x-axis? Are you keeping the x-axis fixed and stretching vertically? Anyway, your final translation looks right.

Comment: I agree with @Billy that the question is rude. We could simply answer that this site is not for private lessons. If "help" means "do whatever I ask and shut up" for ZafarS, he/she should open a good english dictionary and look up that word.

Comment: ZafarS, not to gang up on you, or anything, but I agree with the above two points – there's really no reason why we *should* help, except that we enjoy it, so your tone is a little demanding. You're welcome to *ask* that people answer in a particular way, but if they want to answer in a different way, that's really up to them.

Comment: I'm sorry guys, I was kind off in a bad mood when I asked it. I've got a big test coming up tomorrow and I missed all lessons because of an illness so I basically have to use you guys as my teachers. Also, 'multiply with the x-asis', in my language it is called that, I thought (like often) that I could just directly translate it into english and it would still be understandable, guess not..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac\pi6$ seems to be correct:

You have to consider first, what is happening in 'machine' $\cos$ with your variable $x$.
Those that happen *before* applying $\cos$ will take action horizontally and inverted.

- First plot $\cos x$,
- then $\cos(x-\frac\pi6)$  -- [shift to the *right* by $\frac\pi6$]
- then $\cos(2x-\frac\pi3)$ -- [shrink horizontally by $1/2$]
- then $-4\cos(2x-\frac\pi3)$  -- [reflect along the x-axis because of the $-$ and multiply vertically by 4]
- finally add 2 -- [vertically]